# Share cluster IP range in different Kubernetes clusters

Tags: kubernetes

I am planning to setup different Kubernetes clusters in different data centers which are interconnected.

Is it OK/a good idea to reuse the cluster IP range across the different Kubernetes clusters? That's, different clusters use the same IP range as the cluster IP range to save the IPv4 address space. If not, what will be the potential risks for the reusing?

Answer (score 0):

You can not "share" cluster IP range. Even if you define the same one, each kube cluster will manage it on its own, hence it will be possible to have same clusterIP for different services in different clusters. Kube-proxy will also talk only to the API of the cluster so you will not be able to connect to svc from another cluster by means of "internal" communication.

Although not exactly in this scope, you may find Kubernetes [Federation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/federation/) of interest to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My question may be confusing and I have revised the question. I want to ask whether it's safe to reuse the same IP range in different Kubernetes clusters, which may talk with each other, as the cluster IP range?